# how to display an error message in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, file-upload

i have this code:

```
$allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
$errors = array();
$output = array();

if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){  

     foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

        if(!in_array(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed_extension)){
                die("Die!");
        }
    }

    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

       $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
       $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
       $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

       $file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

         if (!in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension)){
        $errors[$file_name][] = "format $file_extension in image $file_name is not accepted";
        continue;
         }

         if ($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[$file_name][] = "maxsize of 2MB on $file_name has reached";
                    }

         if (count($errors) == 0){

        $dir = "a/b/c";

        if (is_dir($dir)){
            mkdir("a/b/c/tmp_images", 0755);
        }else{
            mkdir("a/b/c", 0755);
            mkdir("a/b/c/tmp_images", 0755);
        }

        $path = "a/b/c/tmp_images"; 
        $prifix = basename($file_name, "." . $file_extension);

        //var_dump ($prifix);

        $uploadfile = $path . "/" . $file_name;

        $x = 0;
        while (file_exists($uploadfile)){
               $x ++;
               $uploadfile = "{$path}/{$prifix}-{$x}.{$file_extension}";
            }

            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $uploadfile)){
               $file_name = basename($uploadfile);
               $output [$file_name] = "OK";

            }else{

            $output[$file_name] = "Failure while Uploading!";
            $errors[$file_name][] = "Failure: Can't move uploaded pictures!";
            }//else...
         }//if(count($errors))...
    }//foreach($_FILES['image']['name']... 
}//if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])...
```

and my problem is, that i dont know how to display the error messages that should be shown, when the array

```
$errors
```

is given. up to now, it just will be displayed:

```
array
```

instead of:

```
maxsize of 2MB on abc.jpg has reached
```

in the html i have this code:

```
<?php if(isset($errors)):?> 

    <div class="form-error-message" id="signup-error-message" style="display": none;">
        <div class="arrow-wrapper">
            <div class="border-wrapper">
            <?php foreach($errors as $error):?>
                <p class="layer-content">
                <?php echo $error;?>
                </p>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

if there is someone who could be that friendly and help me out i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can't you use print_r to display error instead of echo it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've wrote `$errors` as 2-dimensional array:

```
$errors[$file_name][] = 'your message';
```

So to correctly display it use two `foreach`'s instead of one:

```
        <?php foreach($errors as $errorsOnFile):?>
            <?php foreach($errorsOnFile as $error):?>
                <p class="layer-content">
                <?php echo $error;?>
                </p>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe save each error like this:

```
$errors = array();
$errors[] = $file_name . ": this is the error message.";
```

And display like this:

```
if(count($errors) > 0){
    foreach($errors as $e){
        echo $e . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to `print_r` an array, not `echo` it:

`print_r($errors);`

Alternatively, you can show each of the errors individually, like so:

```
foreach( $errors as $innerErrors )
{
  foreach( $innerErrors as $anError )
  {
    echo $anError ."\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: he could echo it, it's in loop, but not selected index in array

Comment: you mean i simply could add: if (count($errors) > 0){foreach($errors AS $error){print_r($error) . "<br />";}} ? that doesnt work. it also will display just "array". thanks.

Comment: @bonny: That's because $errors is apparently an array of arrays. Do the same think for each of the inner arrays.

Comment: i inserted that between "if ($file_size > 2097152){...}" but it doesnt work. now it doesnt display "array" like before. there is nothing now.

Comment: @bonny: You'll need to add thinks like bound checking, to make sure the arrays are populated before you loop over each, and so on.

Comment: i never heard of it before... OMG

Comment: the way i was looking for was written by Botanick. nevertheless thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

How about?

```
echo implode(', ', $errors[$filename]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just echo an array.  You can, however, loops through the elements of the array.

```
foreach($errors[file_name] as $error_message) {
    echo $error_message."<br>";
}
```

This code echos the errors one at a time.